# Hide the BottomNavigationView under the keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In AndroidManifest.xml announced android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

```
<activity
    android:name="com.atfmedia.flopi.ui.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

The lower menu is announced in main_activity.xml , as well as viewing fragments. When the chat_fragment.xml is displayed in the container and the keyboard appears, the BottomNavigationView rises above it.

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/tab_graph"
        tools:layout="@layout/swipes_fragment" />

    <com.atfmedia.flopi.view.ProgressBackground
        android:id="@+id/registrationProgress"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/progressIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/nav_host_fragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

chat_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/chatContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messageRecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/messageInputLayout"
                 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/addPhotoButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_photo" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/photoBadge"
                    android:layout_width="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/addPhotoButton"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/addPhotoButton"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_badge_bg" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/sendImageView"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:alpha="0.75"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_send_msg" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</FrameLayout>
```

I tried to add a KeyboardVisibilityEvent and hide the BottomNavigationView, but then TextInputLayout with the entered message goes under the keyboard.

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(this) { isOpen ->
            if (isOpen) {
                binding.bottomNavView.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                binding.bottomNavView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

I also tried to wrap the container and the lower menu in LinearLayout (so that there was no binding of the bottom of the container to the top of the menu), unfortunately, unsuccessfully.
[image][image]

1. BottomNavigationView above the keyboard
2. BottomNavigationView and TextInputLayout under keyboard (when hiding the bottom menu)

Who has encountered such behavior and what solutions have found ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add
`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
in the root FrameLayout of the chat_fragment.xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

just use this line at the manifest file

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

for example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.AuthActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan
    android:exported="false" />
```